# Can only Drive apps use the Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to write a program that downloads files from my Drive systematically, and uploads them elsewhere in my Drive. In order to use the Drive API, does my program have to be on the Drive app store? Or can it simply be used privately and locally on my computer.

Comment: show us your attempts so far which are somehow preventing you from using the drive api.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your program is in Drive app or what. As long as you implement the code for [download](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) and [upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) codes for the Drive API. You can learn more about ut in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk). You can check here the possible way that you do with the Drive API. Just don't forget that you need to use the [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) in making call with the API.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) is just a [rest api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

> REST-compliant Web services allow requesting systems to access and manipulate textual representations of Web resources using a uniform and predefined set of stateless operations.

Which basically means access runs over a webserver.  Any programing language that can handle a HTTP POST and HTTP Get can access these rest APIs.   You can write an application in java or C# that sits on your local pc and accesses Google drive API.

I am not sure what you mean by drive app store. To my knowledge drive does not have its own dedicated app store.

Note: to access Google APIs you must register your application on [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/)